# How to access VStack from within its onAppear closure?

Tags: swiftui

How do I access the `VStack` from within its own `onAppear` closure? I tried making the stack an instance property of `ContentView` but learned that `VStack` is not a type, but a type constructor. What are my options and what is best practice?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
        }
        .background(.red)
        .onAppear {
            // change VStack background color to blue
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to change the way you are thinking about it: you have "the VStack" - it's immutable. You are changing _the state_ (e.g. background color), so you are creating "the new VStack", not manipulating the old one. So how to do it: for example have a variable: `@State var color: Color = .red` and then manipulate that variable in `onAppear`, and the stack will get itself changed correspondingly without you manipulating it directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the `VStack` internals but you can create a variables that both the `VStack` and the `onAppear` can access.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var vStackBackground: Color = .red
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Test")
        }
        .background(vStackBackground)
        .onAppear {
            self.vStackBackground = .blue
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the `@State` property wrapper only apply to the state of views or other objects as well?

Comment: @lurningtookoad you can use it for any value types like struct, primitives.